# Parallel solving mode with Optimizer solver in Z3

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, z3

Now I want to user parallel solving mode in Z3 with optimizer solver to solver constraint problem using maxSMT but when I set parallel.threads to any number it gives me error. The question is it valid to use Parallel mode with Optimizer solver in Z3 or not ?

I tried to use it with Optimizer but there is the error

```
Z3Exception: b"unknown parameter 'parallel.enable'\nLegal parameters are:\n  ctrl_c (bool) (default: true)\n  dump_benchmarks (bool) (default: false)\n  dump_models (bool) (default: false)\n  elim_01 (bool) (default: true)\n  enable_core_rotate (bool) (default: false)\n  enable_lns (bool) (default: false)\n  enable_sat (bool) (default: true)\n  enable_sls (bool) (default: false)\n  incremental (bool) (default: false)\n  lns_conflicts (unsigned int) (default: 1000)\n  maxlex.enable (bool) (default: true)\n  maxres.add_upper_bound_block (bool) (default: false)\n  maxres.hill_climb (bool) (default: true)\n  maxres.max_core_size (unsigned int) (default: 3)\n  maxres.max_correction_set_size (unsigned int) (default: 3)\n  maxres.max_num_cores (unsigned int) (default: 200)\n  maxres.maximize_assignment (bool) (default: false)\n  maxres.pivot_on_correction_set (bool) (default: true)\n  maxres.wmax (bool) (default: false)\n  maxsat_engine (symbol) (default: maxres)\n  optsmt_engine (symbol) (default: basic)\n  pb.compile_equality (bool) (default: false)\n  pp.neat (bool) (default: true)\n  pp.wcnf (bool) (default: false)\n  priority (symbol) (default: lex)\n  rc2.totalizer (bool) (default: true)\n  rlimit (unsigned int) (default: 0)\n  solution_prefix (symbol) (default: )\n  timeout (unsigned int) (default: 4294967295)\n"
```

Comment: What’s the code you ran to get this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Python interface, try:

```py
from z3 import *

set_param("parallel.enable", True)
set_param("parallel.threads.max", 10)

o = Optimize()
x = Int('x')
o.add(x <= 10)
o.maximize(x)
print(o.check())
print(o.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[x = 10]
```

If you're using the command-line smtlib mode, try:

```
$ cat a.smt2
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert (<= x 10))
(maximize x)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Then:

```
$ z3 parallel.enable=true parallel.threads.max=10 a.smt2
sat
(
  (define-fun x () Int
    10)
)
```

Note that the maxSMT solver is an old-style solver, so I don't think it takes advantage of parallel-solving features in z3. (That is, these settings are unlikely to make any impact on your solving time.)